# Can't find procedure entry point _o__configure_narrow_argv

Tags: windows, codeblocks, procedure

I was trying to use Codeblocks IDE 20.03 in Windows XP when I saw this error message:

The procedure entry point _o__configure_narrow_argv could not be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-private-|l1-1-0.dll.

Is there a fix for this issue?

I am using Windows XP Service Pack 3 Build 2600.

Comment: Update to a more recent and supported OS. Windows XP hasn't been supported for more than 6 years. Time to move on.

Comment: The Codeblocks site indicates Windows XP is supported.

Answer (score 0):

`Codeblocks IDE 20.03` works in `Windows XP 32 Bit` without complaining after the following changes,

1. Download and install *[Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)*
2. Download all the 6 files from [sourceforge.net](https://sourceforge.net/p/codeblocks/code/11196/tree/trunk/src/exchndl/win32/bin/)
3. Extract the files from the downloaded codeblocks-code-r11196-trunk-src-exchndl-win32-bin.zip
4. Copy the files (addr2line.exe, dbghelp.dll, exchndl.dll, mgwhelp.dll, symsrv.dll, symsrv.yes) and replace them in the installation directory where codeblocks.exe is located. (Normally, *C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks*)